# Allow for conditional .filter() and .map() in AngularJS on-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem where I am unable to edit the actual script of the page. That means I cannot add an AngularJS filter, directive, and so on. I am pretty limited, so I can only edit the HTML.

I want to be able to, based on the input from a dropdown, filter an existing list based on the selected property. This is relatively easy, and it can be done like this:

```
myArray.filter(x => x.Type == selectedType)
```

However, AngularJS throws up an error, because it won't allow me to use either `.filter(function(){})` or `.filter(x => x)`. At first I thought it was a problem with lambda, since AngularJS might not support that, but it turns out it's basically impossible to filter an array based on its properties.

This is my initial object:

```
[{
    "id": "random",
    "type": "1",
    "name": "First tag"
},
{
    "id": "random-2",
    "type": "1",
    "name": "Second tag"
},
{
    "id": "random-3",
    "type": "2",
    "name": "Third tag"
}]
```

and if I do `.filter(x => x.type = "2")`, I should be able to get this list back:

```
[{
    "id": "random-3",
    "type": "2",
    "name": "Third tag"
}]
```

Take a lookt at this Plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/yudKIhsB2OQ9Phh0X1am

The "Filtered tags" in the HTML should show the filtered tags based on this condition (which works in normal JavaScript-language):

```
ng-change="vm.FilteredTags = vm.Tags.filter(x => x.type == vm.SelectedValue)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter out `type` property value which is matching `vm.SelectedValue`.

```
<p>Filtered tags: {{vm.Tags | filter: {type: vm.SelectedValue}: true }}</p>
```

Or using alias it would be way simpler, no need to have it on `ng-change`.

```
<div ng-repeat="vm.Tags | filter: {type: vm.SelectedValue}: true as FilteredTags">
   ... your sutff here...
<div>
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense to turn it around like that. Now I just gotta figure out, why my `ng-model` isn't working haha

Comment: what happened with `ng-model`?

Comment: I don't know. It's a bit complex what I'm trying to do. Got it working without making it look too stupid, though! Had to go away from `ng-options` to `ng-repeat` because I'm working with an object.

Comment: @MortenMoulder `ng-options` can also support object, can you open new stackoverflow question about asking the same?